# Dealing with Negative Sign in Expression Tree

Tags: c++, expression-trees, infix-notation

I'm currently making an expression tree and was able to go from infix->tree. However, I'm having difficulty going from tree->infix notation because of the negative sign.

**How do I determine when to put parenthesises for the negative sign when going from an expressionTree to an infix notation?**

For example, converting 1-(1+1) to infix would require you to put parenthesis after the negative signs.

Converting 1-1*(1+1) would not require you to put parenthesis after the negative signs. (Although I could, I'm looking to minimize the number of parenthesis)

My current algorithm for determining parenthesis is this:

```
int opValue() //determines the level precedence of current node
if (node is addition/subtraction)      return 0
if (node is multiplication/division)   return 1
if (node is exponentiation)            return 2
else                                   return 4 //implies it is not an operator

void printInfix()
if (leftNode is not empty)
    if (currentNode is an operator and has a greater opVal than leftNode)
        print "("
        leftNode.printInfix()
        print ")"
    else 
        leftNode.printInfix()

print currentNode

if (rightNode is not empty)
    if (currentNode is an operator and has a greater opVal than rightNode
    or if it is a subtraction operator and the next node's opVal is 0)
        print "("
        rightNode.printInfix()
        print ")"
    else 
        right.printInfix()
```

Something like this doesn't work for 1-(1+1)+1 since it doesn't correctly determine when it needs parenthesis or not. This expression will convert to 1-((1+1)+1).

EDIT: Finally decided to get back to this. Decided to try this method. Will report back if it works:

```
if (node is multiplication/addition)
    if (left is an operator of higher precedence)   add parenthesis and output left
    else    output left

    output node

    if (right is an operator of higher precedence)  add parenthesis and output right
    else    output right
/////////Non-commutative operators//////////////////////////
else if (node is subtraction)   
    if (left is an operator of higher precedence)   add parenthesis and output left
    else if (left is not NULL)  output left     

    output node

    if (right is an operator)   add parenthesis and output right
    else    output right    
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
else if (node is division/power)
    if (left is an operator of higher precedence)   add parenthesis and output left
    else    output left

    output node

    if (right is an operator)   add parenthesis and output right
    else    output node
else    //it is not a operator, or it is a constant, function, or variable
    output node
return stream
```

Comment: You can't merely look at precedence, you'll definitely need to keep parentheses in `1-(1-1)`. What about `a+(b+c)`? It's not generally equivalent to `(a+b)+c`, because of overflow (integer types) or rounding (floating point types).